# How do I place a mob spawner inside another block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Recently, I've seen someone make a custom block, replacing the block texture with a custom texture, and placing a mob spawner directly inside.

I am pretty confused. How do I do this?

Comment: Could you include a source of some sort of where you've seen this? Welcome to arqade!

Answer (score 1):

Try using https://codecrafted.net/blockdesigner. It's for Minecraft 1.12, so it's a bit outdated and will not work properly on 1.16.
Here is a tutorial:

Alternatively, try watching this:

It doesn't explain how to do it fully, so you need to work it out yourself, and update it to later versions (if needed).

Comment: Ooh thanks, i think that's how they did it